# How do I ensure that nested async code will test correctly using Mocha?

Tags: asynchronous, express, mocha.js

I am working with Mocha and am trying to test an API that I am in the process of building.

I am having trouble understanding where to place the `done()` function.

If I place it where it is now, it doesn't execute the callback function of `User.findOne()`.

If I place the done at the bottom of the callback function of `User.findOne()`, then it creates a timeout.

I am relatively new to async and this done function, so can someone help explain why these two cases happen, and how to fix the code so that it will test correctly in Mocha?

```
describe('POST /signup', function() {
  before(checkServerIsRunning); // Need to implement
  it('create a new user if username is unique', function(done) {
    httpReq({
      method : 'POST',
      url    : url + '/signup',
      json   : true,
      body   : JSON.stringify({ 
        username : 'test',
        first    : 'first',
        last     : 'last' })
      },
      function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
          done(err);
        }
        else {
          res.statusCode.should.be.equal(201);
          User.findOne( { username: 'test' }, function(err, user) {
            user.should.have.property('username', 'testy');
            user.should.have.property('firstName', 'first');
            user.should.have.property('lastName', 'last');
            usersToRemove.push(user);
          });
          done();
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place `done()` inside the called to `findOne`.

If you're finding that it times out then either `findOne` is never calling its callback (which is an error!) or it's taking too long to execute.

In this case you could up the timeout by sticking something like `this.timeout(5000)` at the beginning of the test (which increases the timeout to 5 seconds).

In general you wouldn't usually want tests that slow though, so maybe try and figure out why it takes so long.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that I wasn't connected to my database (silly me!) which is why it was timing out.  It should go inside findOne!